# How do you run DalekJS on iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, dalekjs

I've got DalekJS running really well on WinLin, but am interested to know exactly what the process is for running it on iOS.

http://dalekjs.com/docs/ios.html

When running on Windows, for example, I install the DalekJS npm globally, and then install the IE web-driver, before executing my test suite.

On iOS am I expected to do the same thing?  Can you install NodeJS on an iPhone? Is there a difference in doing it on the actual device, vs doing it through the emulator?

Also, what are the current obstacles in making it run on iPad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dalek will not run on the IPad/Iphone etc. itself (neither will or must NodeJS), it uses the native debugging tools that come with the dev environment through [Appium](http://appium.io/).

Unfortunately, due to some changes that happened in MacOS 10.8 & 10.9 (Changes in the user rights management, etc.) it can only do this in the simulator. We are working on bringing back support for "real" devices with the next version of DalekJS.